# Best performance to find an element by ID with Javascript. Array or Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

Let's say I have these two Object, one array and the other one an associative object.

```
var peopleObj = {
    1 : 'Joe',
    3 : 'Sam',
    8 : 'Eve'
};

var peopleArr = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Joe'},
    { id: 3, name: 'Sam'},
    { id: 8, name: 'Eve'}
];
```

Is there a really big overhead when finding an element (by id) with forEach compared to direct associative key ?

```
peopleObj['3'].name = 'New name';

peopleArr.forEach(function(human) {
    if (human.id == 3) {
        human.name = 'New name';
    }
});
```

Comment: well, did you measure it? (also, does it even matter?)

Comment: Yes, of course there is. (Btw, you shouldn't use `forEach`, you can't even `break` from that)

Comment: All performance questions of interest should be measured with a representative data set.  A tool like jsperf can help you do this.

Comment: @Bergi - seriously, you think that's a dup.  It isn't even really the same question and there's no decent answer.  How is anyone's interest served by marking it a dup of that one?

Comment: Here ask about performance difference because in the other post no one speak about perf, it's not a dup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to define "really big," and you'd have to *test it* with your representative data, but the short answer is yes, it's more overhead to use `forEach` than direct property access, for a couple of reasons:

1. Modern JavaScript engines are pretty smart about objects and can optimize direct property access quite well.
2. To use `forEach`, you have to make function calls. Function calls are *extremely cheap*, but they aren't free.
3. In the course of finding the element in the array, you'll be doing various direct property accesses (`human.id`), so right there you're doing the same work you'd've done with direct access, but you're doing it *over and over again*.

Now, not all objects are equal in terms of property access time. In particular, with a modern engine like V8, if you do something to the object that makes the engine throw away its optimizations and fall back on "dictionary mode" (treating the object like a hash table, instead of doing smarter things), property access on that object will be a **lot** slower than on one where the optimizations remain in place. One such operation is `delete`, which causes V8 to put the object in "dictionary mode." [Example on jsperf](http://jsperf.com/dictionary-mode-example) *(Firefox's engine, SpiderMonkey, bizarrely shows an* improvement *with the object `delete` was used on; perhaps it's so fast it's a measurement error, but I ran it several times with consistent results...)*

So in *theory*, if you had a small number of entries in your array, and you built up the array in a way that let the engine optimize it as a true array behind-the-scenes, **and** the object you would have used instead would have been in "dictionary mode," ***maybe*** you might find a use case where `forEach` was faster. It doesn't seem likely, but it's remotely possible.

Comment: Ok so I will not transpose an array to an associative kind of hash map, if the difference is not that big. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @tknew: Well, `forEach` is by its nature going to be O(n), right? But property lookups are implementation-dependent. For an object you don't modify, V8 can do a property lookup on an object with 30 properties just as fast as one with one property, because it generates true classes. Whereas in dictionary mode, it's probably (I haven't looked at the source) using a binary tree or similar.

Comment: @tknew: I don't recall saying the difference wasn't that big. Theory says it'll be quite a bit slower; that doesn't mean the decrease in speed will be a factor in your app.